# Maven release plugin jar-with-dependencies

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-release-plugin, archiva

I've got the maven-assembly-plugin section of the pom file made like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.my.package.MyMainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
             <execution>
                 <id>make-assembly</id>
                 <goals>
                     <goal>single</goal>
                 </goals>
             </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

and the maven-release-plugin like:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <goals>deploy</goals>
                <checkModificationExcludeList>pom.xml</checkModificationExcludeList>
                <tagNameFormat>@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                <providerImplementations>
                    <git>jgit</git>
                </providerImplementations>                  
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-jgit</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

I need to release for Archiva a jar-with-dependency file, but the release:perform command upploads only the jar without any dependencies inside. What am I missing?

Comment: what about package phase, does it however produce an artifact you require?

Comment: could you drop the whole POM file?

Comment: yes it works just fine with package assembly:single

Comment: I just found this https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html and tried adding  <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs> but it didn't work anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok..I'll have to answer my own question. It was just missing the execution phase "package" into the assembly plugin. This is the new one:

```
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.my.package.MyMainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
             <execution>
                 <id>make-assembly</id>
                 <goals>
                     <goal>single</goal>
                 </goals>
             </execution>

             <!-- was missing the following one -->
             <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>

            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Thanks Sergey for pointing me on the package phase.